# Auto populating calendars in excel

Tags: excel, calendar

I have a list of project IDs with start and end dates listed by the numbered day and month. (EX august =8, 1st =1) I have a calendar on another sheet with the month and day numbers in their own cells. I want the project ID to populate in the cell where the month and day numbers on the two sheets match.

Example = if A1 + A2 on Sheet1 Match A1 & A2 on Sheet2, Populate The Project ID here.

Can someone help me figure out the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Stack overflow is a place for suggestions, tips and best practices. Please try to start working on the solution yourself, provide what have you tried till now and seek help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data like this (in Sheet 1 for this example):

[image]

You can use this array formula (don't forget to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to populate the ID when the day and month number match:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6,MAX((A2=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6)*(B2=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6)*ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6)))
```

[image]

The brackets at the beginning and end of the formula is because it's an array formula.

I let you an example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xVmoZ8cGURuwnYF8AsLkozWUIxc5nPmt/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109997475435544900987&rtpof=true&sd=true